# Why does my internet not work when downloading big files?

Tags: networking, internet, download, internet-connection, file-download

When I am downloading files and they get to around 8MB/s, I have to throttle the connection down to at least 6MB/s in order to do anything else online, even regular web pages take soo long to load them it is not even usable. After all that though, I can do a speed test and it says I get around 118MB/s so what gives? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your upload speed?

Comment: Is it 118 MByte/s or 118 Mbit/s? And what speed should you get according to your ISP?

Comment: What kind of files are you downloading? I ask because certain ISPs will throttle torrent downloads. If this is the case, using a VPN may be viable workaround.

Comment: @Michael Shaw Jr. How are you downloading? Via https or torrent? And what's the make model of the router?

Answer (score 2):

Speed test shows megabits per second not megabytes (8 bits equal 1 byte) so 118/8 is about ~14MBps max transfer speed. if you are on a network with multiple devices its possible you are saturating all your bandwidth causing the slow loading.

You could also have a spotty connection causing higher than normal packet loss which would dramatically increase the real data usage of the internet connection you have because tcp/ip transfer would resend any dropped packets thus increasing the total bandwidth used.

An additional possibility is the download is being bottle-necked by your hard drive (because its heavily fragmented) thus causing the rest of your system to slow to a crawl.

I would recommend downloading process explorer

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

and have that running while you download something. If it shows CPU/RAM/HDD above say 70% usage then its possible its a bottle-necking issue.

also just for a test download

https://www.auslogics.com/en/software/disk-defrag/

and do a "Defrag and optimize" and let it scan and finish the Defrag and then try the download again.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I downloaded the process explorer and will check it out next time I download something. However, I don't believe the hard drive is the problem because I have an SSD which I believe doesn't need to and shouldn't be de-fraged

Comment: you are correct on the SSD not needing to be defragged. Hard drives are still the most common storage medium so I made an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

If saturating your broadband connection causes a spike in latency, it usually means your network has a well known bug known as bufferbloat.

Run http://dslreports.com/speedtest to see what your bufferbloat grade is.

If it's bad, look into fixing bufferbloat on your network.

If you don't want to learn all about Smart Queueing and FQ-CoDel yourself, consider buying an EvenRoute.com IQrouter which is a turn-key solution that supposedly does it all for you (I don't have one, so I can't vouch for it, but it's the only device I know of that specifically attempts to fix/mitigate bufferbloat for your whole network from a single box).

Comment: I have seen you recommend this before, I'm pretty sure bufferbloat is only an issue in fifo queuing. What not just use qos properly? And attack the problem at the congestion?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Bufferbloat is when a box (typically a middlebox, but could be an endpoint host) never drops packets despite prolonged congestion, and is never able to drain its queues. This hides the congestion from the TCP endpoints, which prevents TCP's Congestion Control algorithms from kicking in. So all it does is add needless latency and make congestion worse. Fixing bufferbloat is really about getting your middleboxes to stop hiding congestion from TCP so TCP can do the right thing. So it *does* attack the problem at the congestion. Using QoS to work around this bug would be a kludge.

Comment: understood this can happen in larger networks with intermediary equipment in between. i was referring to home network gear, considering you have no access to interface buffers in consumer gear. i have always just gone the QOS route with people complaining about this issue. (home users seem to never want to buy new anything). do you know of a workaround for the home user? (other than host OS buffers?) Regards

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Bufferbloat is a huge problem on residential broadband links. As the slowest link in the path, it's where congestion and bufferbloat is most likely to build up. Home users on a budget should see if they can install a Smart Queueing (FQ-CoDel) capable firmware distro such as OpenWrt or DD-WRT on the router at the head of their network. Ideally all network middleboxes should do SQ, but with SQ and just enough traffic shaping to make your router a slight bottleneck, you can let your SQ router do ECN (or smarter dropping) before bloated queues can build up anywhere else.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart If you're interested, here's a good writeup where an engineer at Ookla Speedtest.net used the "make your FQ-CoDel router a slight bottleneck so it can drop packets before bufferbloat builds up anywhere else" trick on his home network with excellent results. https://medium.com/speedtest-by-ookla/engineer-maximizes-internet-speed-story-c3ec0e86f37a

Comment: interesting read. I think we have been arguing the same point just using different terminology. I guess using dd-wrt and pfsense for so long the problem was a non issue for me. I always just setup docsis networks with the bottle neck on the user side. I'm now interested in fairQ after reading that. I have been using HSFC for years on PFsense. Thanks for the link.

Comment: don't know if you have been exposed to accedian networks products. I just got my hands on one of the carrier grade eitherNID "zero latency traffic shapers". I just got a couple on eBay for 80 bucks. Check them out, they are almost worth their weight in gold.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Thanks for the tips. I think the difference in our approaches is that I don't use QoS when the real problem is BufferBloat. I suppose one could argue that the minimal traffic shaping I do (to make the FQ-CoDel router a slight bottleneck) is akin to QoS, but unlike what's commonly meant by QoS, I never prioritize one type of traffic over another. Once you fix the bufferbloat bug on your home network / residential broadband, everyone's lag goes away and you don't need to mess with traffic priorities anymore.

Comment: In most cases I have to prioritize, I'm usually in Soho/small business environments. So VOIP prioritization isn't really a choice. Regards!